# recaptcha with ajax and PHP in simple form login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I make a form of login With One button submit and email input. But when I wanted to add **`recaptcha`** **google v2**. I found many problems.
Please help me.

**index.php:**

```
require_once 'includes/main.php';


/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle visits with a login token. If it is
    valid, log the person in.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['tkn'])){

    // Is this a valid login token?
    $user = User::findByToken($_GET['tkn']);

    if($user){

        // Yes! Login the user and redirect to the protected page.

        $user->login();
        redirect('protected.php');
    }

    // Invalid token. Redirect back to the login form.
    redirect('index.php');
}



/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle logging out of the system. The logout
    link in protected.php leads here.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['logout'])){

    $user = new User();

    if($user->loggedIn()){
        $user->logout();
    }

    redirect('index.php');
}


/*--------------------------------------------------
    Don't show the login page to already 
    logged-in users.
---------------------------------------------------*/


$user = new User();

if($user->loggedIn()){
    redirect('protected.php');
}



/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle submitting the login form via AJAX
---------------------------------------------------*/


try{

    if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){

        // Output a JSON header

        header('Content-type: application/json');

        // Is the email address valid?

        if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Please enter a valid email.');
        }

        // This will throw an exception if the person is above 
        // the allowed login attempt limits (see functions.php for more):
        rate_limit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        // Record this login attempt
        rate_limit_tick($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['email']);

        // Send the message to the user

        $message = '';
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = 'Your Login Link';

        if(!User::exists($email)){
            $subject = "Thank You For Registering!";
            $message = "Thank you for registering at our site!\n\n";
        }

        // Attempt to login or register the person
        $user = User::loginOrRegister($_POST['email']);


        $message.= "You can login from this URL:\n";
        $message.= get_page_url()."?tkn=".$user->generateToken()."\n\n";

        $message.= "The link is going expire automatically after 10 minutes.";

        $result = send_email($fromEmail, $_POST['email'], $subject, $message);

        if(!$result){
            throw new Exception("There was an error sending your email. Please try again.");
        }

        die(json_encode(array(
            'message' => 'Thank you! We\'ve sent a link to your inbox. Check your spam folder as well.'
        )));
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){

    die(json_encode(array(
        'error'=>1,
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    )));
}

/*--------------------------------------------------
    Output the login form
---------------------------------------------------*/

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title></title>

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- The main CSS file -->
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="login-register" method="post" action="index.php">

            <h1>Login or Register</h1>

            <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" autofocus />
            <p>Enter your email address above and we will send <br />you a login link.</p>

            <button type="submit">Login / Register</button>

            <span></span>

        </form>

        <footer>
            <a class="tz" href="#">#</a>
            <div id="tzine-actions"></div>
            <span class="close"></span>
        </footer>

        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**ajax script.js:**

```
$(function(){

    var form = $('#login-register');

    form.on('submit', function(e){

        if(form.is('.loading, .loggedIn')){
            return false;
        }

        var email = form.find('input').val(),
            messageHolder = form.find('span');

        e.preventDefault();

        $.post(this.action, {email: email}, function(m){

            if(m.error){
                form.addClass('error');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
            else{
                form.removeClass('error').addClass('loggedIn');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
        });

    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        form.addClass('loading');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        form.removeClass('loading');
    });
});
```

A full week ago I try. But no result. I need it for my site script. Please help me, I no longer know if I will continue the script without captcha.

thank you all.

i try put this code in ajax but not work

```
$(function(){



var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('recapptcha', {
    'sitekey' : '-------key----------'
  });
};
onloadCallback();


    var form = $('#login-register');

    form.on('submit', function(e){



  if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You can't proceed!");
  } else {  



        if(form.is('.loading, .loggedIn')){
            return false;
        }

        var email = form.find('input').val(),
            messageHolder = form.find('span');

        e.preventDefault();

        $.post(this.action, {email: email}, function(m){

            if(m.error){
                form.addClass('error');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
            else{
                form.removeClass('error').addClass('loggedIn');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
        });

 }//recaptcha end tag

    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        form.addClass('loading');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        form.removeClass('loading');
    });
});
```

i dont know how i add code captcha with ajax?

**update:**

bro (madalinivascu) i put now your 1st code javascript in script.js and it works good because it sends two values to the http header email:xxxxx@xxx.xx and captcha:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...

The new code in script.js become :

```
$(function(){

    var form = $('#login-register');

    form.on('submit', function(e){

        if(form.is('.loading, .loggedIn')){
            return false;
        }

        var email = form.find('input').val(),
            messageHolder = form.find('span');

        e.preventDefault();

                //This code i added
                $.post(this.action, {email: email, captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()}, function(m){

            if(m.error){
                form.addClass('error');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
            else{
                form.removeClass('error').addClass('loggedIn');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
        });

    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        form.addClass('loading');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        form.removeClass('loading');
    });
});
```

But in the index.php file I did not know where I put this code:

```
$secret="YOUR_SECRET";
$response=$_POST["captcha"];

$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
if (!$captcha_success->success) {
  //This user was not verified by recaptcha, send error message

}
else {
  //This user is verified by recaptcha, continue

}
```

I tried several attempts and did not succeed.
index.php Code:(dont work)

```
    <?php

    require_once 'includes/main.php';


    /*--------------------------------------------------
        Handle visits with a login token. If it is
        valid, log the person in.
    ---------------------------------------------------*/


    if(isset($_GET['tkn'])){

        // Is this a valid login token?
        $user = User::findByToken($_GET['tkn']);

        if($user){

            // Yes! Login the user and redirect to the protected page.

            $user->login();
            redirect('protected.php');
        }

        // Invalid token. Redirect back to the login form.
        redirect('index.php');
    }



    /*--------------------------------------------------
        Handle logging out of the system. The logout
        link in protected.php leads here.
    ---------------------------------------------------*/


    if(isset($_GET['logout'])){

        $user = new User();

        if($user->loggedIn()){
            $user->logout();
        }

        redirect('index.php');
    }


    /*--------------------------------------------------
        Don't show the login page to already 
        logged-in users.
    ---------------------------------------------------*/


    $user = new User();

    if($user->loggedIn()){
        redirect('protected.php');
    }



    /*--------------------------------------------------
        Handle submitting the login form via AJAX
    ---------------------------------------------------*/



    ////////////////////start code recaptcha/////////////////
$secret="YOUR_SECRET";
$response=$_POST["captcha"];

$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
if (!$captcha_success->success) {
  //This user was not verified by recaptcha, send error message

}
else {
  //This user is verified by recaptcha, continue

}
    ////////////////////end code recaptcha/////////////////

    try{


        if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){

            // Output a JSON header

            header('Content-type: application/json');

            // Is the email address valid?

            if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                throw new Exception('Please enter a valid email.');
            }

            // This will throw an exception if the person is above 
            // the allowed login attempt limits (see functions.php for more):
            rate_limit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

            // Record this login attempt
            rate_limit_tick($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['email']);

            // Send the message to the user

            $message = '';
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = 'Your Login Link';







            if(!User::exists($email)){
                $subject = "Thank You For Registering!";
                $message = "Thank you for registering at our site!\n\n";
            }

            // Attempt to login or register the person
            $user = User::loginOrRegister($_POST['email']);


            $message.= "You can login from this URL:\n";
            $message.= get_page_url()."?tkn=".$user->generateToken()."\n\n";

            $message.= "The link is going expire automatically after 10 minutes.";

            $result = send_email($fromEmail, $_POST['email'], $subject, $message);

            if(!$result){
                throw new Exception("There was an error sending your email. Please try again.");
            }

            die(json_encode(array(
                'message' => 'Thank you! We\'ve sent a link to your inbox. Check your spam folder as well.'
            )));
        }








    }
    catch(Exception $e){

        die(json_encode(array(
            'error'=>1,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        )));
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------
        Output the login form
    ---------------------------------------------------*/


    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title></title>

            <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- The main CSS file -->
            <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
                            <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
        </head>

        <body>

            <form id="login-register" method="post" action="index.php">

                <h1>Login or Register</h1>

                <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" autofocus />
                <p>Enter your email address above and we will send <br />you a login link.</p>

                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcBtjwUAAAAAAFmvS_I2XPhiNGw9vyTdphNp9pq"></div>

                <button type="submit" name="submit">Login / Register</button>

                <span></span>

            </form>

            <footer>
                <a class="tz" href="#">#</a>
                <div id="tzine-actions"></div>
                <span class="close"></span>
            </footer>

            <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Please Help me. and thank you very much.
Where I put code recaptcha in index.php file:

Comment: **I found many problems** where,how many,what do they say?

Comment: I do not know where to add the CAPTCHA code Google is in the AJAX js or in the php file or the two.

Comment: in both the front-end and in the backend,in the front-end you append the html and the js, in the backend you check the response received over the ajax

Comment: i try to add this code to file php but not work

i try to add this code to file php but not work 


$response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
 $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
 $data = array(
  'secret' => '---secret-key---',
  'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
 );
..............................................

Comment: i don't see a trace of captcha in your code,where is the captcha code?

Comment: I do not know where I put the code, my brother pls helpe me. where to put it?

Comment: read my second comment

Comment: the html youp put it in the form , the js at the bottom of the page, the php in the save/login function

Comment: did you read the documentation for google captcha ?

Comment: The problem is not in form code. the problem is adding captcha to script.js and index.php

Comment: yes i read and i have other form php working good with captcha. but this form with ajax dont know how work

Comment: you need to send the `g-recaptcha-response` to the php over ajax

Comment: Yes but if you can help me.pleas tell me how?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: i have updated the question please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Send the captcha response over the ajax to the php script:

```
$.post(this.action, {email: email,captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()}, function(m){
```

in the php you need to so something like

```
$secret="YOUR_SECRET";
$response=$_POST["captcha"];

$verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
$captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
if (!$captcha_success->success) {
  //This user was not verified by recaptcha, send error message

}
else {
  //This user is verified by recaptcha, continue

}
```

Comment: I placed the code in php. But I do not know how to put a full Java code.

Comment: what java ? what has php and javascript got to do with java?

Comment: I mean java script my brother.

Comment: See the answers I have put the full code in answer at the bottom.

Comment: i can't see any answer

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts I found the correct way to add the capcha to the form.
The correct code is:
script.js(ajax):

```
$(function(){

    var form = $('#login-register');

    form.on('submit', function(e){

        if(form.is('.loading, .loggedIn')){
            return false;
        }

        var email = form.find('input').val(),
            messageHolder = form.find('span');

        e.preventDefault();

        //$.post(this.action, {email: email}, function(m){

                $.post(this.action, {email: email, captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()}, function(m){

            if(m.error){
                form.addClass('error');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
            else{
                form.removeClass('error').addClass('loggedIn');
                messageHolder.text(m.message);
            }
        });

    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        form.addClass('loading');
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        form.removeClass('loading');
    });
});
```

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/main.php';


/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle visits with a login token. If it is
    valid, log the person in.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['tkn'])){

    // Is this a valid login token?
    $user = User::findByToken($_GET['tkn']);

    if($user){

        // Yes! Login the user and redirect to the protected page.

        $user->login();
        redirect('protected.php');
    }

    // Invalid token. Redirect back to the login form.
    redirect('index.php');
}



/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle logging out of the system. The logout
    link in protected.php leads here.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['logout'])){

    $user = new User();

    if($user->loggedIn()){
        $user->logout();
    }

    redirect('index.php');
}


/*--------------------------------------------------
    Don't show the login page to already 
    logged-in users.
---------------------------------------------------*/


$user = new User();

if($user->loggedIn()){
    redirect('protected.php');
}


/*--------------------------------------------------
            get result of captcha
---------------------------------------------------*/
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
    {
        //form submitted

        //check if other form details are correct

        //verify captcha
        $recaptcha_secret = "-----your-secret-key-----";
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['captcha']);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

    }

/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle submitting the login form via AJAX
---------------------------------------------------*/

try{


    if(!empty($_POST)  && isset($_POST["captcha"]) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){

        // Output a JSON header

        header('Content-type: application/json');

        // Is the email address valid?

        if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Please enter a valid email.');
        }

       if(!$response["success"] === true){
            throw new Exception('Please check captcha.');
        }

        // This will throw an exception if the person is above 
        // the allowed login attempt limits (see functions.php for more):
        rate_limit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        // Record this login attempt
        rate_limit_tick($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['email']);

        // Send the message to the user

        $message = '';
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = 'Your Login Link';

        if(!User::exists($email)){
            $subject = "Thank You For Registering!";
            $message = "Thank you for registering at our site!\n\n";
        }

        // Attempt to login or register the person
        $user = User::loginOrRegister($_POST['email']);


        $message.= "You can login from this URL:\n";
        $message.= get_page_url()."?tkn=".$user->generateToken()."\n\n";

        $message.= "The link is going expire automatically after 10 minutes.";

        $result = send_email($fromEmail, $_POST['email'], $subject, $message);

        if(!$result){
            throw new Exception("There was an error sending your email. Please try again.");
        }

        die(json_encode(array(
            'message' => 'Thank you! We\'ve sent a link to your inbox. Check your spam folder as well.'
        )));
    }


}
catch(Exception $e){

    die(json_encode(array(
        'error'=>1,
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    )));
}

/*--------------------------------------------------
    Output the login form
---------------------------------------------------*/

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>#</title>

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- The main CSS file -->
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
                        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="login-register" method="post" action="index.php">

            <h1>Login or Register</h1>

            <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" autofocus />
            <p>Enter your email address above and we will send <br />you a login link.</p>

                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="------yoursitekey------"></div>

            <button type="submit" name="submit">Login / Register</button>

            <span></span>

        </form>

        <footer>
            <a class="tz" href="#"></a>
            <div id="tzine-actions"></div>
            <span class="close"></span>
        </footer>

        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The error I had here:
I put this code: `if(isset ($ _ POST ["g-recaptcha-response"]))`
But what worked with me was this: `if(isset ($ _ POST ["captcha"]))`
and i was put this code:`if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){...}`
But the correct code in this case is: `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){...}`
and i also didn't put some codes in the correct place. The important thing is that I succeeded. Thank God and everyone who helped me or tried to help me. Especially thank to brother 'madalinivascu'